# Compare any value column A with any value in column B

Tags: r

I want to compare two columns:

#### column A:

```
IGHV3-21*02,IGHV3-30-5*04    
IGHV3-30*18,IGHV3-30-5*01    
IGHV5-51*01    
IGHV5-76*01
```

#### column B:

```
IGHV3-21*02  
IGHV3-30*18    
IGHV5-51*01
IGHV6-51*01
```

and match if any item in column A match any item of column B (or viceversa)

Output expected should be:

#### column Match:

```
TRUE  
TRUE  
TRUE  
FALSE
```

in R, the most simple way could be:

```
df$columnA %in% df$columnB
```

But this is not considering both items at a given position and will return:

```
FALSE  
FALSE  
TRUE  
FALSE
```

Any idea how to handle words separated by comma in a position to use %in%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_rows(columnA, sep = ',') %>% 
   mutate(match = columnA == columnB) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% mutate(columnA = toString(columnA)) %>% 
   mutate(match = if_else(any(match == TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
   distinct() %>% ungroup() %>% select(-id)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  columnA                    columnB     match
  <chr>                      <chr>       <lgl>
1 IGHV3-21*02, IGHV3-30-5*04 IGHV3-21*02 TRUE 
2 IGHV3-30*18, IGHV3-30-5*01 IGHV3-30*18 TRUE 
3 IGHV5-51*01                IGHV5-51*01 TRUE 
4 IGHV5-76*01                IGHV6-51*01 FALSE
```

Data used:

```
df
                    columnA     columnB
1 IGHV3-21*02,IGHV3-30-5*04 IGHV3-21*02
2 IGHV3-30*18,IGHV3-30-5*01 IGHV3-30*18
3               IGHV5-51*01 IGHV5-51*01
4               IGHV5-76*01 IGHV6-51*01
```

Comment: that's great perfect, what about if I have more than 2 in column A and more than 2 in column B? because I have also those cases...

Comment: @fusion.slope, I assume you mean if you had comma separated values in A as well as B. In that case, you'd need to separate rows for B as well and use the same logic.

Comment: yes more than 2 comma separated values in A and/or B and at least one in the two is matching..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be useful:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df1 %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(V1,sep=',') %>% left_join(df2 %>% mutate(Match=T)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Val=ifelse(any(Match & !is.na(Match)),T,F)) %>%
  select(-Match) %>%
  summarise(V1=paste0(V1,collapse = ','),
            Val=sum(Val)) %>%
  mutate(Val=ifelse(Val>0,T,F)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  V1                        Val  
  <chr>                     <lgl>
1 IGHV3-21*02,IGHV3-30-5*04 TRUE 
2 IGHV3-30*18,IGHV3-30-5*01 TRUE 
3 IGHV5-51*01               TRUE 
4 IGHV5-76*01               FALSE
```

Some data used:

```
#Data1
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("IGHV3-21*02,IGHV3-30-5*04", "IGHV3-30*18,IGHV3-30-5*01", 
"IGHV5-51*01", "IGHV5-76*01")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

#Data2
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("IGHV3-21*02", "IGHV3-30*18", "IGHV5-51*01", 
"IGHV6-51*01")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `base::charmatch`. Here is a simple function wrapper over it.

```
`%pin%` <- function(x, y) {
  out <- logical(length(x))
  p <- unique(charmatch(y, x, 0L))
  out[p[p > 0L]] <- TRUE
  out
}
```

Data

```
x <- c("IGHV3-21*02,IGHV3-30-5*04",
"IGHV3-30*18,IGHV3-30-5*01",
"IGHV5-51*01",
"IGHV5-76*01")

y <- c(
  "IGHV3-21*02",  
  "IGHV3-30*18",
  "IGHV5-51*01",
  "IGHV6-51*01"
)
```

Usage

```
> x %pin% y
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr` to break down the rows with commas into different rows:

```
df1 <- df %>% separate_rows(columnA,sep=",")
```